# Is there a service method that can be requested that has the `fromParams`?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there an object I can request i.e. a service that has the `stateParams` from the previous state? I know I can get them in the `$stateChangeStart` event and that is fine I just don't want to duplicate code unless I have to by creating my own service that holds that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is no. There [is a documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router), which mentions these services:

- [$urlRouter](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouter)
- [$state](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)
- [$uiViewScroll](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$uiViewScroll)
- [$view](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$view)
- [$resolve](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$resolve)
- [$templateFactory](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$templateFactory)
- [$urlMatcherFactory](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$urlMatcherFactory)

*But, I'd say, that implementing the custom one, which would be filled on every `$stateChangeStart` should not be an issue... And it could at the end do even more...*

Comment: I ended up just creating my own model to hold the state information. There is this http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/previous but it was throwing a bunhc of errors in my app and writing my own was really easy so I just went downt hat path.